Load hdfs file to hive table from path contains space
I'm trying to create a hive table from parquet file with partition.
Create External table a(col1 string, col2 string) partitioned by (col3 string) stored as parquet location '/qa/app/project/';
msck repair table a;

/qa/app/project/col3=all eq 10%35
this space in path results into ddl error.
I can't remove space from path as these values are decided by client. Is there anyway to load the file with space in path?

Hive can handle this if you first use a staging table with no partitions to import the data. Then, move the data from the staging table to your partitioned table. Follow these steps:
Creating a staging table (no partition):
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE staging_table (col1 STRING, col2 STRING, col3 
STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/qa/app/project/';

Reading data from the staging table (note that col3 includes values with spaces):
> SELECT * FROM staging_table;
OK
value1a value1b all eq 10%35
value2a value2b another value
value3a value3b yet another value

Setting up your target table:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE a (col1 STRING, col2 STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (col3 STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/tables/a';

Enabling dynamic partitioning (this step is needed to avoid semantic errors during data insertion):
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

Inserting data from the staging table into the target table:
INSERT INTO TABLE a PARTITION (col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM staging_table;

Verifying the final result:
> hadoop fs -ls /tables/a
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          1 2024-04-03 18:33 /tables/a/col3=all eq 10%2535
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          1 2024-04-03 18:33 /tables/a/col3=another value
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          1 2024-04-03 18:33 /tables/a/col3=yet another value


Hi Sercan, thank you for your help. But it is not working for me, it is showing partition value as NULL
